# \Drupal\search_api\Entity\Index::load('INDEX_ID'); returns null

Tags: search

I am trying to create a module that executes a search -- I tried to utilize the documentation for calling a search in code but

$index = \Drupal\search_api\Entity\Index::load('INDEX_ID');

gives me $index == NULL so the very second line

$query = $index->query();

blows it up.  I tried replacing 'INDEX_ID' with 'default_index' but that didn't help.  Search API is definitely enabled.  Any idea why \Drupal\search_api\Entity\Index::load would keep giving me NULL?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you need to create an index first.

Go to

```
/admin/config/search/search-api
```

and create your index then replace the **INDEX_ID** in your code with the id you have set for the new index.

You might have to create a server too if you don't have any configured. I have used the default DB Search API. Enable ***Database Search***.

```
/admin/modules?filter=search
```

Then create the server where you created the index:

```
/admin/config/search/search-api
```

Then configure the index to use the server and enable the index.

*Don't forget to process the indexing for your new index. :)*